# Is there's a way to speed up my php code which parse XML files

Tags: php, performance, xml

I'm developing a web application and we are using XML as a database and I'm using Linux as a platform and centos 6.5 as a server. Changing some value would make a lot a lot of changes in about six XML files.

So here's the problem: Pressing button save after editing, adding, deleting takes about one or one and half minutes or more! This is because my code has to update about six XML files, log files and the crontab file. I wonder if there's any thing similar to threads in PHP?

I have my functions and all code I want, I just want to know how php can be used in a new way to make performance better. Can you guide me even by links to read?

I don't know what's exactly this problem is called to search about it. I'm still a beginner.

here's the update function I'm using :

```
 public static function update($tableName, $fieldsToUpdate, $newValues, $value = NULL) {
        //Load XML file
        $fileName = G_APP_SCRIPTS_PATH . "/XMLS/xmls/" . $tableName . ".xml";
        $xml = new DOMDocument;
        $xml->load($fileName);
        //Load XSD file
        $xsdfileName = G_APP_SCRIPTS_PATH . "/XMLS/xsds/" . $tableName . ".xsd";
        $xsd = new DOMDocument;
        $xsd->load($xsdfileName);
        //Generate Xpath
        $path = c_XML::generateXPath($xml, $xsd, $fieldsToUpdate, $value);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
        //Query nodes to update
        $nodes = $xpath->query($path);
//        print_r($nodes->item(0));
        //If number of new values < number of elements to update,means we have to update
        //all specified elements in the XML without any condition
        if (count($newValues) < $nodes->length) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length / count($newValues); $i++)
                $newValues = array_merge($newValues, $newValues);
        }
        //Iterate over the nodes to update
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
            $oldNode = $nodes->item($i);
            for ($index = 0; $index < count($fieldsToUpdate); $index++) {
                //Find the associated index in the $fieldsToUpdate array
                if (strcmp($oldNode->nodeName, $fieldsToUpdate[$index]) === 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Create new node with the old node's name
            $newNode = $xml->createElement($oldNode->nodeName);
            //var_dump($newNode);
            //if the new value is an array,means we have to update an inner node
            if (is_array($newValues[$index])) {
                //go to the desired node in XSD and get its children elements,
                //to know their format
                $xsdxpath = new DOMXPath($xsd);
                $children = $xsdxpath->query("/xs:schema/xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='" . $oldNode->nodeName . "']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element");
                //convert the $chlidren node list to an array to pass the createNode function.
                for ($c = 0; $c < $children->length; $c++) {
                    $childrenArray[$c] = $children->item($c);
                }
                //create the desired node
                c_XML::createNode($xml, $xsdxpath, $newNode, $childrenArray, $newValues[$index]);
            }
            //If the new value is not an array
            else
                $newNode->nodeValue = $newValues[$index];
            //Replace old node with new node
            $parent = $oldNode->parentNode;
            $parent->replaceChild($newNode, $oldNode);
        }
        //Validate & save XML
        $isValid = c_XML::validateXMLtoXSD($xml, $xsdfileName);
        if ($isValid == 1) {
            $xml->save($fileName);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

and when user update a value I use this way in updating other xml files :

```
  private static function change_value_in_xml_file($old_value, $new_value) {
            $all_nodes = c_XML_h::select(tables::xmlfile, '*');
           $nodes = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($all_nodes); $i++) {
               $nodes[$i] = array();
//just get the nodes i want
               $nodes[$i][0] = $all_nodes[$i][0];
               $nodes[$i][1] = $all_nodes[$i][3];
            }
            //find old value and replace it with new value
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                $newValues[0] = $new_value;

                if ($node[1] == $old_value) {
                    $id_to_update = $node[0];
                    $fieldsToSelect[0] = xmlfile:: value;
                    c_XML_h::update(tables::xmlfile, $fieldsToSelect, $newValues, $id_to_update);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: dan1111's answer is pretty much spot on, but out of curiosity, what is the size of one of these XML "table" files?

Comment: it's not that big , contains 5 nodes (23 byte)
but it's slow because they are many .
now size of all 11 kbyte 
imagine when they grow :D

Comment: OK, that's a bit strange - updating (only) 6 XML files should not typically take too long, depending on the size of the file of course (my gut feel says that this is at least 10 to 100x slower than it should be, based on your description).  You could try to profile your code to see which parts are the slowest, it's a useful skill to have in general, and you often get a surprising answer.  Having said that, don't use XML files as a DB, dan1111's answer already gives some ideas of why it's a bad idea, but it's just scratching the surface.

Comment: don't know how to profile it . I'm doing it manually now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML is not a very good choice for a database that needs a lot of updating, because text files are not random access:  you must parse the whole file *every time* you want to read or write a single element.  You might be able to improve your code slightly, but XML isn't going to be fast.

Some other problems you may have:

- This will scale very poorly.  As the size of your database increases, your code will get much, much slower.
- Concurrent updates will be a problem.  Could you have two people performing actions that will update the database at the same time?  If so, at best one action would fail to complete.  At worst, it could leave your data in a corrupt state.

I would suggest you bite the bullet and replace it with a real database.  You appear to have nicely abstracted your data access into functions, so all you have to do is rewrite those functions to access a database rather than read and write XML files.

(Also keep around the old XML functions to aid in moving the data.  Once you have written the database interface, you can make a little program that will read all of your data in XML using the old functions, then write it to the database using the new functions.)

Comment: +1, although I think you shouldn't be so politically correct, using XML files in this fashion (as you would an actual DB) is not just "not very good".  It's horrible.  It should be easy to fix, however, as you point out.

Comment: thanks so much for great information . but you know what I can't replace them without agreement of supervisor . and he insist on xml files as a storage tool .
so I'm trying to improve his code as much as I can

Comment: @Sally, that's an unfortunate situation.  What kind of a website is this?  How large do you expect it to be in actual use?

Comment: it's a database administration web application .
xml files are used for recording tasks ,errors ,events , servers and users of the app which they are not usually that large .

Comment: I'm recording now how long every insert , delete and update operation is taking by watching ajax post in the firebug . want to find what function causing that slowness

Comment: @Sally - What??? A database administration app that doesn't use a database?  My head just exploded (sorry, I know it's not your fault).

Comment: you are right :$ :$ . but supervisor who developed last version of code used XML because as he says there weren't a need to real db . files are not that large